# How to update column_name in information_schema.columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Unable to update the column_name column in information_schema.columns

I have a table named 'knd' in MS-SQL server. Now I want to alter the column names of all the columns in this table in this way:

for example, my column names in this table are: Fuel category, fuel type, end date, start date

I want to update these names to [Fuel category], [fuel type], [end date], [start date]. i.e column names must include [] and the updation should be done in one shot.

What I have tried:

```
update INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
Set COLUMN_NAME = CONCAT('[',COLUMN_NAME,']')
where TABLE_NAME = 'knd'
```

I get the below error:

Ad hoc updates to system catalogs are not allowed.

I tried to reconfigure with override as below, but didn't work:

```
exec sp_configure 'allow updates','1';
go
reconfigure with override
go
```

even if I have to use exec sp_rename, how can I do it for all columns in one shot. I believe using sp_rename requires more manual intervention as my column names might change tommorow .

Can someone please help to accomplish this?

Comment: Why would you want your column's name to **include** brackets?! If you have an object called `[Fuel category]` you would have to reference it as `[[Fuel category]]]` in your SQL. Don't do this!

Comment: You can not edit the information schema tables, it is for information only.  You need to do updates for changes.  You can use the information schema tables to find all the columns you want and do dynamic SQL updates by looping through all the values in the information schema tables

Comment: Are you *sure* you want to rename your columns that way? Typically, the `[column]` syntax is encountered when you need to escape columns with spaces in the name. That is, the column's *name* should remain `Fuel category`, but *client code* must write that as `[Fuel category]`. You cannot rename the column and expect client code to then pass the name correctly, because the correct escaped name then becomes the mighty confusing `[[Fuel category]]]`. If your client code has trouble with these names, consider removing the spaces (i.e. `Fuel_category`), or fix your client code to use `QUOTENAME`.

Comment: Do NOT use brackets in your column names, very bad and could cause many issues

Comment: If @JeroenMostert is right with his hunch, and your application is struggling to handle a name with a space, then I can assure you it is going to struggle far more with a column called `[Fuel category]`.

Comment: Also, what do you mean *"as my column names might change tommorow"*. Why are you column names changing on a frequent basis? Object names should be pretty static. it's your data that changing a lot, not its definition.

Comment: In case you're wondering: it is categorically impossible to make `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` return the information in a form a naive application that constructs dynamic SQL will like more, at least it is without voiding the warranty of your SQL Server installation. Do not mess with system views. If you cannot slip in `QUOTENAME` in the client code (the proper solution) you could consider creating a new view and have the client code use that instead of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.

Comment: Okay. Thanks guys for letting me know more on handling information_schema.columns. I am able to handle this with QUOTENAME as @JeroenMostert mentioned . Below is my simple query to perform this.

Answer (score 2):

First: This is a terrible idea, as everyone wrote in the comments. Adding square brackets to column names will only force you to refer to the columns with double square brackets - to refer to a column named `[fuel type]` you will have to write `[[fuel type]]]`.

Second, You can't directly update system tables or the views that relies on them. Everything in the [`sys`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/catalog-views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) schema and in the [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/system-information-schema-views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) schema is readonly. To rename a column in a view, you must write an [`alter view`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) statement, or use [`sp_rename`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-rename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). To rename a column in a table, you must write an [`alter table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) statement or use `sp_rename`.
That being said, it's best to first find all objects that depends on the column you want to rename, becuase renaming a column will not rename every reference to it, so you might break stuff when renaming.
You can query the built in table valued function [`sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-sql-referencing-entities-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to get dependencies of an object in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Quotename does the needful in my case as suggested by @jeroen-mostert in one of the above comments!!.

Below is my simple code snippet to perform this for all the columns in my table set.

```
Select  STUFF((SELECT N',' + QUOTENAME(C.COLUMN_NAME)
                  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
                  WHERE C.TABLE_NAME = 'knd'
                  FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value(N'.',N'nvarchar(MAX)'),1,1,N'')
```

Result is as follows:

[Start Date_(MM-DD-YYYY)],[End Date_(MM-DD-YYYY)],[mode],[scac],[fuel category],[Fuel Type],[Base],[Escalator],[Surcharge],[FSC @ $3.2],[Step],[Co_ID]